# Add ID for Input Tag in forms from DropDown

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I created dropdown with choice :

```
Choice 1: Show 1 form
Choice 2: Show 2 forms
...
Choice 3 : Show 4 forms
```

All forms are similar.

I want to add id for `Name` input tag .This is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#selectBox").change(function() {
    var element = $('form').children('div:eq(0)');
    var html = [];
    var idname = document.getElementsByClassName("name");
    for(var i=1; i<parseInt($(this).val()); i++){
      html.push(element.clone());
      idname[i].id = "name-" + i;
    } 
    $('#outputArea').html(html);
  })

});
```

My code don't run.
Can you help me?

Thank you so much!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Q8IX.png)

Comment: please, specify your problem. what does "doesnt run" mean? nothing happens? error? what kind of error? how does your html look?

Comment: add your html code related to this